# ajax output has no style

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have an index file which has a search form. the result of the search is a table. my original table in index.php uses datatables and both style and functionality works perfect. here is part of my index.php file that shows the result taken from the result of searchDate.php file:
    
                From:  
                
                To:

```
            <select name="dateOption" id="dateOption">
                <option value="order"> Order </option>
                <option value="inventory"> Inventory </option>
                <option value="po"> PO# </option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="searchinput" id="searchinput" />
            <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="getDate();" />
        </form>
```

and here is the getDate() function:

```
function getDate() {
                $.post('searchDate.php' , {   dateKey: $("#searchinput").val(), 
                                              selected: $("#dateOption").val(),
                                              from: $("#date").val(),
                                              to: $("#date2").val()
                                              },
                    function(output) {
                        $('#mainTable').empty();
                        $('#orderSearch').empty();
                        $('#newOrder').empty();
                        $(".line").hide();
                        $("#loadNewInvoice").hide();
                        $('#searchResult').append(output);
                        $('#searchResult').css('display','block');
                        $('#searchResult').show("blind");

                });
            }
```

the result is a table with the same id and class as my original working table. however, the result is not functional and has no style.
Thank you in advance.
Edit:
here is the css and my datatable configuration just in case:

```
table.display {
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
width: 100%;


}

table.display thead th {
padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
* cursor: hand;

}

table.display tfoot th {
padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
font-weight: bold;
}

table.display tr.heading2 td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

table.display td {
padding: 3px 10px;
}

table.display td.center {
text-align: center;
 }
```

datatable:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var oTable = $('#theTable').dataTable({
"bPaginate": true,
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"iDisplayLength": 15,
"oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
    },
"aoColumnDefs": [
  { "asSorting": [ "desc" ], "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ]

} );
```

Comment: well the css comes from datatables demo file i just modified it a bit. it is the same css as my original table in the page so i am certain that the styles must work because both tables are identical but the result of search obviously has less rows as the original one.

Comment: see in firebug if css styles are applied on your tables or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem some times ago. Jquery require that all yours ids are unique in the page. If this rule isn't respected, it simply does not work!

So, if you change the id of the table your code should work as expected.

Comment: I actually did try that but it didn't work either. However, i figured it out. all i had to do was to link all my java script files and css styles in my searchDate.php file. I had the impression that since my output table comes with an id and a class, the page must recognize them and apply the style. But apparently this is not the case.